# Php writes XML file with no values

Tags: php, dom

I have a script that reads values from a mysql database. With the values received i want to make a XML file.

The file is written but with no values.
I can't figure it out. Here is the complete source code:
http://www.segasiauto.ro/tmp/writexml.txt

Can someone help?

Thanks, 
Sebastian

**EDIT**

Solved. There was a problem with the array. I added the data directly to `createNodeText`

Comment: What does the data from the database look like? Have you checked if there even are any data retrieved?

Comment: Please (a) narrow your code to the smallest example that still shows the problem, (b) post it here, where we know it won't disappear, so this question will stay useful in the future, and (c) post the result file you're getting so we know what you mean by "with no values". Thanks!

Comment: @Ancide the data is ok. checked the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully what you're doing:

```
  $product[] = array(
  'id' => $id,
  'name' => $tip,
  'category' => $tip_produs,
  'model' => $tip_imp,
  'keywords' => $keywords,
  'price' => $pret,
  'available' => "1",
  'canBeOrderedOnline' => "0",
  'details' => $details,
  'pictures' => "picture",
  'currency' => $valuta,
  );
```

and then

```
$doc->createTextNode( $product['id'] ));
```

will never get you want you want.
Of course it is empty. There is nothing in there.

Comment: Darn. I did't notice it had been solved already. You should have accepted your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at the end of your file.
You use:

```
$doc->saveXML('document.xml');
```

That does not output anything, the function returns a xml string. In order to send the xml string to your browser you should echo it:

```
echo $doc->saveXML('document.xml');
```

See also [`DOMDocument::saveXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php)

Comment: Or use `$doc->save('document.xml');` to save to a file. (See http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php)

Comment: i tried both. if i use `echo $doc->saveXML();` nothing is printed out. 
if i use `$doc=>save('document.xml')` a file is written but with  just the tags with no values.